# Save in my custom admin page and redirect to the saved object

Tags: plugin-development, database

I'm building the admin page for my plugin, I'm saving well in the DB, but when I press the button Save the page is reloaded with an empty form. I'm looking how can I save the form but make a redirect (I don't know if this would be a redirect) but when the page is reloaded display the object recent saved and show the corresponding data in each field, for example, when we write a post, first we are in `post-new.php` but when we save WP take us to `post.php?post=195&action=edit`. Until now I have this:

```
public function puzzle_manager(){
        global $wpdb;

        $file = file_get_contents('puzzle_manager.php', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
        if($file == false){
            echo 'file not found';
        }
        else{
            echo $file;
        }

        $default = array(
        'puzzle_title' => '',
        'image' => '',
        'rows' => '',
        'cols' => '',
        'timer' => '',
        'movements_counter' => '',
        'original_button' => '',
        'numbers_button' => '',
        );

        $item = shortcode_atts( $default, $_REQUEST );
        $wpdb->insert( 'wp_puzzle' , $item );
    }
```

Comment: what is id of the wp_puzzle table?

Answer (score 0):

You can call them with `$last_item = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_puzzle ORDER BY your_table_id DESC LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A  );` and put manualy every item in your inputs at the form

```
public function puzzle_manager(){
            global $wpdb;

            $file = file_get_contents('puzzle_manager.php', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
            if($file == false){
                echo 'file not found';
            }
            else{
                echo $file;
            }

    $last_item = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_puzzle ORDER BY your_table_id DESC LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A  );

    if(!empty($last_item)){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r_($last_item);
    //you must put manualy every $last_item value in your form, example $last_item['puzzle_title'] in puzzle_title input
    echo '</pre>';
    }

            $default = array(
            'puzzle_title' => '',
            'image' => '',
            'rows' => '',
            'cols' => '',
            'timer' => '',
            'movements_counter' => '',
            'original_button' => '',
            'numbers_button' => '',
            );

            $item = shortcode_atts( $default, $_REQUEST );
            $wpdb->insert( 'wp_puzzle' , $item );
        }
```